# Get rendered output of EJS template and store in variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, ejs

main.js

```
socket.on('chatMessages', (message) => {
  let chatMessageHtml = ejs.render('chat_message', {message: message});
})
```

chat_message.ejs

```
<%= message %> //not working
```

I have set code but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the callback function to get rendered content from EJS template.

```
var ejs  = require('ejs');
var data = {message: "Hello World"};

ejs.render('chat_message', data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        // throw err;
    } else {
        //output of EJS rendered template
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```